# Connecting to a self signed mongodb server though nodejs driver doesn't require `pem` key

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs mongodb driver to connect to a self signed mongodb instance. The MongoDB version is 4.0.0. And the nodejs driver version is 3.1.1. Below is the command to launch a self signed mongodb instance:

```
mongod --port 27018 --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile mongodb.pem  --dbpath data
```

when I connect to this server with nodejs, I can use below options without specifying `pem` file:

```
const options = {
  ssl: true,
};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27018', options, (err, driver) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

I wonder why the connection option doesn't require `pem` file. Why does it work just with a ssl option.